# How to check if string contains certain amounts of letters and numbers C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to see if a string contains 3 letters + 2 numbers + 1 letter or number. This is the standard of a Swedish license plate nowadays.

Is it possible to see if the string got the standard ABC123 or ABC12D and preferably in that order?
How do I do it as simple as possible?

```
if(theString.Length == 6)
{
    if(theString.Contains(...)
    {
```

Comment: If order matters, use regexp. If order does not matter, sort the string before applying a regexp.

Comment: Note that the letters I, Q and V are not used, see swedish [Wikipedia](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registreringsskyltar_i_Sverige#Teckenserier).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Regex for this:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$");
// ^ start of string
// [A-Z] a letter
// {3} 3 times
// [0-9] a number
// {3} 3 times
// $ end of string

string correct = "ABC123";
string wrong = "ABC12B";

Console.WriteLine(correct + ": " + (r.IsMatch(correct) ? "correct" : "wrong"));
Console.WriteLine(wrong + ": " + (r.IsMatch(wrong) ? "correct" : "wrong"));

// If last character can also be a letter:
r = new Regex("^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9A-Z]$");
// ^ start of string
// [A-Z] a letter
// {3} 3 times
// [0-9A-Z] a number
// {2} 2 times
// [0-9A-Z] A letter or a number
// $ end of string

Console.WriteLine(correct + ": " + (r.IsMatch(correct) ? "correct" : "wrong"));
Console.WriteLine(wrong + ": " + (r.IsMatch(wrong) ? "correct" : "wrong"));
```

Comment: The last character can be a digit or letter.

Comment: That's what the question says: `contains 3 letters + 2 numbers + 1 letter or number`

Comment: Jop. Misunderstood the question. Modified the answer.

Comment: It's new for the year ^^

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this using `Regex`:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"^[A-Z]{3}\d{2}(\d|[A-Z])$"))
{
    // matches both types of numberplates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will check using Regex

```
String input="ABC123";
var result = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$") || 
             Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}$");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: I'd give this as answer too if I could, thanks you!